# Find exact file name from the file name with complete path stored in database

Tags: sql

I need to find exact file name by executing SQL query on the table containing the file_name column .In file_name column the complete path of files are stored like D:/Workspace/app.js

I can find app.js with query Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM details 
WHERE file_name LIKE '%app.js'
```

but the problem is if I write the query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM details 
WHERE file_name LIKE '%p.js'
```

it lists app.js file also . So anyone could guide me how to get an exact match for file name from the database if file names are stored with the comple path?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM details WHERE file_name LIKE '%/app.js'` ?

Comment: when using `%`, you just mean to find all column that are suffixed with `p.js`, hence there is no solution to do the work. you can just give more character to hint mysql to get lesser data. Or you can just find tuple by using `ID` column. lastly, you may find the data by yourself, after `mysql` fetching more than one line of data, do the selection by you own.

Comment: @JB NIzet :: I do have a variable containing file name app.js ,I need to match app.js from database with that variable containing file name and do operation on that file .If I use your approach I need to add '/' in varible before file names but i dont want this.Thanks

Comment: @ammy: So, assuming `fileName` is the variable containing the file name (app.js), use `String sqlParameterValue = "%/" + fileName;` Where is the problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet:I used the approach you suggested but it also doing operation on file if file name is p.js. I tried to retrive from database Select file_name from details where file_name LIKE '%\p.js' :this query is listing path of files containing app.js

Comment: @JB Nizet: The problem is some file_names are stored with forwared slash(D:/Workspace/app.js) and some are with backward slash(D:\Workspace1\app.js).plz suggest something thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM details WHERE file_name LIKE '%/app.js' or file_name LIKE '%\app.js'`

Comment: Its fine but when you run query like SELECT * FROM details WHERE file_name LIKE '%/p.js' or file_name LIKE '%\p.js'  it gives app.js files also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you ,
I got the result I wanted

```
     sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE file_name RLIKE ?";
     ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setString(1, "[[:<:]]"+fname+"[[:>:]]");
```

This gives the exact string that fname varible contains.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM details WHERE file_name LIKE '%/app.js' OR file_name LIKE '%\app.js'
```

Comment: no not of use i do have file name in a variable and I have to match with files in database ..

Comment: The problem is some file_names are stored with forwared slash(D:/Workspace/app.js) and some are with backward slash(D:\Workspace1\app.js)

Comment: @ammy Hey I changed the query

Comment: If this is SQL Server, the two parts of the condition can be combined like this: `... WHERE file_name LIKE '%[\/]app.js'`.

Answer (score 0):

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern. So you'll never find `%app.js` because there are no `xxxxapps.js`.

Comment: There must be some way ,using regex or something ?